# Evaluating limits and testing continuity

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I have trouble evaluating a few limits and discussing the continuity of a few functions

Discuss the continuity of
$$ 
f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos^{2n}{x} 
$$

$$
g(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log{(2+x)} - x^{2n}\sin{(nx)}}{1+x^{2n}} 
$$
at $x=1$

and

$$
h(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{1 + (2\sin x)^{2n}}
$$

It would be helpful to discuss without using diffrentiation. Or atleast not using them directly. The range of $x$ for limits $1$ and $3$ weren't specified in the text i came across. So i'm assuming x spans across $\mathbf{R}$

Comment: Please specify range of x for your first and third limit.

Comment: For the first one, Hint:

Take the log of the function and evalutate the limit of the function with (1/n)-->0 with cosx ranging from 1 to -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;a_n\in\Bbb R\;\;\text{and}\;\;|a_n|<1\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^n=0\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;\forall\,x\neq k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;|\cos x|<1\end{align*}$$

This shall help you with at least $\;f,h\;$ . For the second one, with arithmetic of limits and using the continuity of the involved functions:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log(x+2)-x^{2n}\sin nx}{1+x^{2n}}=\frac{\log 3-\sin n}{1+1}=\frac{\log 3}2$$

and this doesn't depend on $\;n\;$ ...

Now, for *arbitrary* but fixed $\;|x|< 1\;$ :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(2+x)-x^{2n}\sin nx}{1+x^{2n}}=\log(2+x)\;\ldots\\{}\\
$$

Answer (score 1):

*Partial Solution:*

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\cos^{2n}x\right)$$

Recall $|r|<1\implies r^n\to0$.

Consequently if $-1<\cos x<1$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\cos^{2n}x\right)=0.$$

On $(0,\pi),~|\cos x|<1$ whence $f\equiv0$ on $(0,\pi).$

Since $0<1<\pi,~$ $f$ is continuous at $1.$

---

$$h(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{x}{1 + (2\sin x)^{2n}}$$

For $\dfrac{\pi}{6}<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2},~1<2\sin x\implies(2\sin x)^{2n}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty\implies h(x)=0$

Thus $h\equiv0$ on $\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and hence $h$ is continuous at $1\in\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right).$